# Groupby() the words with comma separator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an DataFrame in csv:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4   col5
0   A       1,5     2,5     3,5   
1   B       C       3,5     4,5    5,5
2   D       6,5     7,5     8,5   
3   B       E       9,5     10,5   11,5
```

and use:

```
df1 = df.stack().to_frame()
m = df1[0].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x :x.str.isalpha().ne(1).cumsum())
df2 = df1.groupby([df1.index.get_level_values(0),m]).sum().unstack().add_prefix('col_')
df2.reset_index(0).reset_index(drop=True) 
df2.columns = [col[1] for col in df2.columns]
df2.set_index('col_1', inplace=True)
```

I getting:

```
      col_0     col_1     col_2     col_3
0         A       1,5       2,5       3,5
1        BC       3,5       4,5       5,5
2         D       6,5       7,5       8,5
3        BE       9,5      10,5      11,5
```

and I would like to get:

```
     col_0     col_1     col_2     col_3
0         A       1,5       2,5       3,5
1       B,C       3,5       4,5       5,5
2         D       6,5       7,5       8,5
3       B,E       9,5      10,5      11,5
```

In real data A, B, C, D, E are all words, so I need to use comma separator.
You have some ideas how to do it?

Comment: Explain the rationale behind this grouping?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This has already been clarified :)

Comment: So, that doesn't mean you shouldn't explain what you wanted to do, just because someone took a shot at an answer and happened to guess correctly what you wanted. It's quite obvious to me that adjacent elements that are not grouped by comma must be grouped so, but that isn't obvious to everyone. Remember, the goal of StackOverflow is to create a repository of good, clear Q&As that future users can learn and benefit from. It is not meant to help _just you_.

Comment: ok, i'll have that in mind at next post :)

Comment: another question ,,,LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need select column by `[0]` and then `apply` with `join`:

```
df2 = (df1[0].groupby([df1.index.get_level_values(0),m])
             .apply(','.join)
             .unstack()
             .add_prefix('col_')
             .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df2)
  col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3
0     A   1,5   2,5   3,5
1   B,C   3,5   4,5   5,5
2     D   6,5   7,5   8,5
3   B,E   9,5  10,5  11,5
```

Comment: I was close, I did not notice the need for df1 [0]. thanks for the help :)